# Setting up django on a virtual machine

Tags: python, django, apache

I have a virtual machine running peppermint os 2 (basically ubuntu).

I've been trying to follow the following tutorial: http://jeffbaier.com/articles/installing-django-on-an-ubuntu-linux-server/

and so far everything has worked out as the tutorial has stated. My Apache httpd.conf file looks like the following:

```
ServerName localhost

MaxRequestsPerChild 1

    SetHandler python-program
    PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
    SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE myproject.settings
    PythonPath "['/home/<my_user_name>/django_projects'] + sys.path"

    SetHandler None

    SetHandler None

    SetHandler None

    SetHandler None
```

Whenever I try and and go into "localhost/", it shows me the /var/www/ folder (the index.html file that says "It works!") and not a django startpage that should come up. The contents of my /var/www are "admin_media" and "media"

What do I need to do?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/) or [uwsgi](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/Quickstart), it's easier to config, robust, and much faster.

you could also get help at [django doc - use django with mod_wsgi](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/deployment/modwsgi/)

as you are using ubuntu, the install of mod_wsgi is easy:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi
```

if this does not have mod-wsgi enabled, do as following:

```
cd /etc/apache2/mod_available
cp mod_wsgi.* ../mod_enable
sudo service apache2 restart
```

for using mod_python, the apache config is:

```
ameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:8000
Listen 80
Listen 8000

WSGIDaemonProcess xxxx display-name=%{GROUP}
WSGIProcessGroup xxxx
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  xxxx
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/xxx/xxxx/xxxx.wsgi

    Alias /js "/home/xxx/xxxx/xxxx/public/js"
    <Location "/js">
        SetHandler None
    </Location>
    <Directory "/home/xxx/xxxx/xxxx/public/js">
       Order Deny,Allow
       Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

NameVirtualHost *:8080
<VirtualHost *:8080>
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/xxxx/xxxx/wsgi_handler.py
        #WSGIDaemonProcess xxxx_com22 user=xxxx processes=1 threads=10
        #WSGIProcessGroup xxxx_com1

        Alias /upload/ "/home/xxxx/xxxx/upload/"
        <Directory /home/xxxx/xxxx/upload/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
Listen 8080
```

and for using uwsgi, my recommend is using nginx + uwsgi, if you are interesting, I'll post the tutorial and configuration.